# How to select a radio button on a page using htmlunit (Web Scraping)

Tags: javascript, java, forms, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrape a donation page using htmlunit. I need to fill inputs like nickname, message, amount and then select the method of payment in order to print the url to the payment. I have no problem with filling text inputs, but when I try to select the radio button (payment method), it doesnt work. It just leaves the default button selected.

Page: https://tipo.live/p/bartlomiej-skowron (Polish language)

My code:

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://tipo.live/p/bartlomiej-skowron"));
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
        
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);


        JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
        HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);

        HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton)form.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").get(0);
        HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("username");
        HtmlTextArea message = form.getTextAreaByName("message");
        HtmlTextInput amount = form.getInputByName("amount");
        HtmlInput payment = form.getInputByValue("7"); //radio button

        username.type("Nickname");
        message.type("Example Message");
        amount.type("25");

        payment.setChecked(true); // it doesnt work

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(500);

        button.click();

        while(true){
            if (manager.getJobCount() <= 0) break;
        }
        
        HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println(currentPage.getUrl());
```

I also tried to execute javascript, but it doesn't work too:

```
        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://tipo.live/p/bartlomiej-skowron"));
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);

        page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"7__input\").click();");
        page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementsByName(\"amount\")[0].value=\"25\";");
        page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementsByName(\"message\")[0].value=\"Example Message\";");
        page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementsByName(\"username\")[0].value=\"Nickname\";");
        page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"octf-btn octf-btn-primary octf-btn-icon\")[0].click();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have done some debugging on this. Looks like changing the payment method (the radio button) triggers a server roundtrip to inform about this.

This is not the case if you change the selection using HtmlUnit. The log shows the event is triggered

```
Firing Event change (Current Target: HTMLElement for HtmlRadioButtonInput[<input x-model="selected" autocomplete="off" id="7__input" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="7">]);
```

A a first guess the event handler might not be registered because the loading of one used js library failed (during opening the page)

```
Loading external JavaScript: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.jsLoad response for GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.jsCookieSpec 
....
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ) after formal parameters (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js#7)
```

A deeper analysis requires more time - please open a fix against HtmlUnit on GitHub and i will try to work on this.